# Maven on Jenkins vs Eclipse tests

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, junit4

Hi guys i have a problem i run my tests in eclipse (not using maven just right click run test) than push the project to git repository.
Afterwards Jenkins pulls those test and runs them by using mvn test(Using maven 3).Here I have some problems 
1. I am using junit 4 in eclipse i putted @Ignore annotation on 5 test to see that all my tests are passing. And here is a stange part her are the results .

Eclipse : Runs 407/407(5 ignored)

Jenkins (using Maven): Tests run: 396, Failures: 3, Errors: 1, Skipped: 5

Maven on Windows : Tests run: 407, Failures: 9, Errors: 0, Skipped: 5

Can some one please explain to me why dose it happens.

Another issue that might be related is  all my test extend class i created that has the following Annotations in hes declaretion

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

@ContextConfiguration("classpath:context.xml")

any way in this class i created @BeforeClass method for database initialization but when it runs in jenkins this method is not called or atleaset hes logging is not working.

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml file? Furthermore the tests sounds more like integration tests and not like unit test?

Answer (score 0):

can't tell much without seesing tests that fail and pom. a few possibilities:

- classpath badly configured
- tests uses files or other resources that are being addressed using OS specific notation
- tests depends one on another and are run in random order
- one tests are executed multiple times (eg because they inherit from other tests) and different tools report it differently

maybe a combination of above